# Problem building Android_Core (package app_manager does not exist)

Tags: ros, turtlebot, android-core, rosjava, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following this tutorial to setup my Android environment

http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_android/Tutorials/groovy/Installation

Currently I'm at this stage in the tutorial

```
roscd android_core
# Note: you may need to adjust the argument to the `--target` option based
# which Android API version you're using.

# You may have to kill gradle if it's already running.

android update project --path ./android_gingerbread_mr1/ --target android-17
android update project --path ./android_honeycomb_mr2/ --target android-17
cd android_gingerbread_mr1
../gradlew debug
cd ../android_honeycomb_mr2
../gradlew debug
```

When i do the first ../gradlew debug it throws java errors saying 'app manager' does not exist. The problem is I installed 'app manager' and can roscd to 'app_manager'

Error

```
lucid@lucid-MacBookPro:~/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1$ ../gradlew clean debug
:android_gingerbread_mr1:clean
> Building > :android_gingerbread_mr1:deployLibs > Resolving dependencies ':andr:android_gingerbread_mr1:deployLibs
:android_gingerbread_mr1:updateProject
Updated local.properties
No project name specified, using project folder name 'android_gingerbread_mr1'.
If you wish to change it, edit the first line of build.xml.
Added file /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/build.xml
Added file /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/proguard-project.txt
:android_gingerbread_mr1:debug
Buildfile: /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/build.xml

-set-mode-check:

-set-debug-files:

-check-env:
 [checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 22.0.5
 [checkenv] Installed at /home/lucid/Desktop/android-sdk-linux

-setup:
     [echo] Project Name: android_gingerbread_mr1
  [gettype] Project Type: Android Library

-set-debug-mode:

-debug-obfuscation-check:

-pre-build:

-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 18.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for android_gingerbread_mr1...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.3
[gettarget] API level:        18
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/res
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/gen
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/classes
    [mkdir] Created dir: /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/dexedLibs
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for android_gingerbread_mr1...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
     [echo] Handling aidl files...
     [aidl] No AIDL files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
[renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling Resources...
     [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
[buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
    [javac] Compiling 31 source files to /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/bin/classes
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:35: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.AppList;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:36: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.ListApps;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:37: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.ListAppsRequest;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:38: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.ListAppsResponse;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:39: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StartApp;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:40: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StartAppRequest;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:41: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StartAppResponse;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:42: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StopApp;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:43: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StopAppRequest;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:44: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StopAppResponse;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private ServiceResponseListener<StartAppResponse> startServiceResponseListener;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StartAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private ServiceResponseListener<StopAppResponse> stopServiceResponseListener;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StopAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:60: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private ServiceResponseListener<ListAppsResponse> listServiceResponseListener;
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ListAppsResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:61: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private ArrayList<Subscriber<AppList>> subscriptions;
    [javac]                                  ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class AppList
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:62: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private Subscriber<AppList> subscriber;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class AppList
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void addAppListCallback(MessageListener<AppList> callback)
    [javac]                                                    ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class AppList
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             ServiceResponseListener<StartAppResponse> startServiceResponseListener) {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StartAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             ServiceResponseListener<StopAppResponse> stopServiceResponseListener) {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StopAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:105: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             ServiceResponseListener<ListAppsResponse> listServiceResponseListener) {
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ListAppsResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:44: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StartAppResponse;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:45: error: package app_manager does not exist
    [javac] import app_manager.StopAppResponse;
    [javac]                   ^
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         ServiceClient<StartAppRequest, StartAppResponse> startAppClient;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StartAppRequest
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:112: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         ServiceClient<StartAppRequest, StartAppResponse> startAppClient;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StartAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:116: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     StartApp._TYPE);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable StartApp
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:120: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         final StartAppRequest request = startAppClient.newMessage();
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StartAppRequest
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         ServiceClient<StopAppRequest, StopAppResponse> stopAppClient;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StopAppRequest
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:129: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         ServiceClient<StopAppRequest, StopAppResponse> stopAppClient;
    [javac]                                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StopAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:133: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     StopApp._TYPE);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable StopApp
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:137: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         final StopAppRequest request = stopAppClient.newMessage();
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StopAppRequest
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         ServiceClient<ListAppsRequest, ListAppsResponse> listAppsClient;
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ListAppsRequest
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:146: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         ServiceClient<ListAppsRequest, ListAppsResponse> listAppsClient;
    [javac]                                        ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ListAppsResponse
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:150: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     ListApps._TYPE);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable ListApps
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/AppManager.java:154: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         final ListAppsRequest request = listAppsClient.newMessage();
    [javac]               ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ListAppsRequest
    [javac]   location: class AppManager
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:252: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 .setStopService(new ServiceResponseListener<StopAppResponse>() {
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StopAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class RosAppActivity
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:254: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     public void onSuccess(StopAppResponse message) {
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol: class StopAppResponse
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:282: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 .setStartService(new ServiceResponseListener<StartAppResponse>() {
    [javac]                                                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StartAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class RosAppActivity
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:284: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     public void onSuccess(StartAppResponse message) {
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol: class StartAppResponse
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:311: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 .setStopService(new ServiceResponseListener<StopAppResponse>() {
    [javac]                                                             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class StopAppResponse
    [javac]   location: class RosAppActivity
    [javac] /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/RosAppActivity.java:313: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     public void onSuccess(StopAppResponse message) {
    [javac]                                           ^
    [javac]   symbol: class StopAppResponse
    [javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
    [javac] Note: /home/lucid/android/android_core/android_gingerbread_mr1/src/org/ros/android/robotapp/Dashboard.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 39 errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/lucid/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:712: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/lucid/Desktop/android-sdk-linux/tools/ant/build.xml:726: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 2 seconds

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':android_gingerbread_mr1:debug'.
> Command 'ant' finished with (non-zero) exit value 1.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 3.704 secs
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/73951/problem-building-android_core-(package-app_manager-does-not-exist)/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-08-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's not finding the app manager messages. These are compiled when you gradle rosjava messages. Possibly did you install the app_manager package after you gradled rosjava_messages?

If that is the case, you'll need to clean and rebuild rosjava_core, android_core and then android_apps. In some cases with these kinds of errors you also need to clean out your local maven repository as well (~/.m2) which is where the jar's go, but that shouldn't be necessary in this case.

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2013-08-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1